# how can access to an API which is have a token with Axios in vuejs?

Tags: rest, vue.js, axios

I have an API that has a JSON file, I gonna get information from that with Axios but it has Token and I don't know how can use it anybody can help me?
here it's API

‫‪https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/picks.json‬‬

I try this but its didn't work and gave me error 401 and this
GET https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/picks.json%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC 401 (Unauthorized)

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    async getDataFromApi() {
      const res=await axios.get("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/picks.json‬‬");
      console.log(res.data)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

please, someone helping me

Comment: Have you signed up as a developer and got your API key / tokens? https://developer.nytimes.com/get-started

Comment: @johnal yes, I have the token

Comment: did you try to add it to the query string? `const res=await axios.get("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/picks.json‬‬?api-key=YOUR-KEY-HERE");`

Comment: @johnal  it gave me this

`{
  "fault": {
    "faultstring": "Failed to resolve API Key variable request.queryparam.api-key",
    "detail": {
      "errorcode": "steps.oauth.v2.FailedToResolveAPIKey"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: one step closer at least.. when you are asking someone (this case New york times) a question (that needs authentication = API key) you have to tell the service who you are.. this error message seems to tell something like your key is wrong.. I will check out their site, back soon..

Comment: @johnai thanks, and sorry, your right my question was bad, here my token please try it and guide me.


‫‪hjOa0PgKqC7zm86P10F3BQkTuLsEV4wh‬‬

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223909/discussion-between-johnal-and-mohammad).

Answer (score 1):

401 Error means you not authenticated. you must add a token in axios authorization header and send it with your HTTP request.

```
const res = await axios.get('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/picks.json', {
  headers: {
    authorization: 'my secret token'
  }
});
```

This is the hard code way, for more efficiency, you must define `interceptors` for axios to send the token with every HTTP request. see this: https://gist.github.com/srph/38f67a10e991b6cb2d83